# Define To: field from from various values

Tags: powershell

In a CSV file I have various columns and two of those are for emails.  Each row within these email columns have a group of emails.

I want to be able to send to these email addresses from a script.
I have everything setup and working, except for the `TO:`.

The idea of the script is that it loops each line of the csv and generates an email grabbing values from the cells of that row into various parts of the body. Then it sends of an email and loops back to the next line of the CSV to do the same, and so on until it reaches the end of the CSV file.

I'm having issues to plug a variable for the email columns, I'm guessing because the emails don't have "quotations".

How do I bring these in?

In a nutshell for the code

1. data is imported CSV
2. a loop is created foreach line of imported data
3. smtp, from, to, subject, attachments, body variables are defined
4. then the sendmail-message command is provided.
5. close the loop

   ```
    ##For the purpose of this, the emaildata.csv looks like this sample:

   "NameGroup","emailGroupA","emailGroupB"
   "Groupabc","a.b@b.com;c.a@b.com","xyv@b.com;xxd@b,com"
   "Grouptrd","ca.r@b.com;as.b@b.com","aaa@a.com;bbb@b.com"
   "Groupghd","dd.r@b.com;dd.b@b.com","dddaa@a.com;ddddddb@b.com"


   $DataDir = "C:\Users\acastrellon\Documents"
   $Data= import-csv $DataDir\emaildata.csv
   foreach ($i in $Data) {

   $NameGroup = $i.NameGroup
   $TeamA = $i.emailGroupA.replace(';',"`n")
   $TeamB = $i.emailGroupB.replace(';',"`n")


   function send-email {


   $smtpserver = " server.smtp"
   $from = "myemail.com"
   $to = $TeamA,$TeamB

   send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $smtpServer

   }

   [string] $subject = "some text here: $NameGroup"
   #[string] $attachment = "not here yet"
   [string] $body = "

   Text here that calls out $NameGroup

   This also lists: $TeamA

   This here lists $TeamB

   Done"

   send-email -subject $subject -attachment $attachment -body $body

   }
   #this should loop to get data from next line of csv and generate a new email with data.
   ```

Comment: Show us what code you've tried so far.

Comment: are you joking? can you paste the actual relevant code?

Comment: `Send-MailMessage -To $to`

Comment: Sorry Guys I've modified to show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike a batch file where environment variables have a global impact to the current session, PowerShell isolates variables in different scopes.

You're referencing the two `$TeamA` & `$TeamB` variables *inside* a function but you set their values *outside* the function. Because the function scope (where they are read) is different to the script scope (where you set them) those variables will be empty inside the `send-email` function in your script.

Have a read on [PowerShell scopes](https://www.howtogeek.com/203778/how-scopes-affect-powershell-scripts/) as you'll need to make some changes to your script functions; to either read the variables from the script scope (`$script:TeamA`) or to pass them [into the function as a parameter](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/04/07/powershell-functions-with-parameters.aspx)

Comment: sorry, my bad should have used a better example.  I've modified the post with more accurate samples and some code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be relevant to the code you've provided.

Comment: So what if I remove the function to keep it all in script?

Comment: Whats happening is when I provide $to = $TeamA,$TeamB, this returns an error where a recipient must be specified.  And for some reason it throws the error, it sends one email, but it's not looping.  Where as if I provide a single address in the To field, it sends the emails and loops each line.

Comment: Try replacing `$TeamA = $i.emailGroupA.replace(';',"``n")` & 
`$TeamB = $i.emailGroupB.replace(';',"``n")` with `$TeamA = $i.emailGroupA.split(';')` and
`$TeamB = $i.emailGroupB.split(';')`

Comment: Thanks James this worked.  I added it as a separate variable as the newline was needed for the use of variable in the body.  How would I ensure that an email that is in the to field and also in the cc field, would then only be included in the to field and excluded from the cc field, but still email the other emails in the cc field.